# When selecting navbar option it disappears from the dropdown HTML JS

Tags: javascript, html

I think I'm doing something wrong but can't really figure out what.

I have a simple navigation dropdown to select a specific year. When I click on the year that I want, it should replace the label Year with the number.

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Year</button>
    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
        <a onclick="tiptip(this)">2000</a>
        <a href="">2001</a>
        <a href="">2002</a>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
function tiptip(e) {
    $('.dropbtn').html(e);

}
</script>
```

For now this is what I have. When selecting, for example 2000, I want that the text inside the button changes from 'Year' to '2000'. I'm able to do this, however the option '2000' seems to disappear from the dropdown.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is it mandatory the use of jquery or do you like solutions in pure js too with no framework?

Comment: @willywonka no it is not mandatory the use of jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Into the original question you say you have a **drop down**, but I don't see any drop down in your code. So I will propose some different solutions one based on your code with the **div HTML element** with minor adjustments, and the other with an actual **drop down, the HTML select element**... and a **bonus** solution.
You will be free to choose and further adapt and optimize the one that best fits your needs. Also I will indicate you a short / one liner version of each solution.

Click on the blue button **Run code snippet** down each code snippet to actually see each one in action.

To see in action the **one liner version** you just have to:

1. click on the relative **Copy snippet to answer**
2. remove the 3 rows as indicated by the comment
3. de-comment the commented row as indicated by the comment
4. run it by clicking on **Run code snippet**

### 1st Solution: using the "div" HTML element:

```js
function changeYear(event)
{
    let tgtEl = document.getElementById("myBtnId");
    let srcEl = event.target;
    tgtEl.innerHTML = srcEl.innerHTML;

    // The one liner version (remove or comment the 3 rows above and de-comment the following one):
    // document.getElementById("myBtnId").innerHTML = event.target.innerHTML;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">

    <button id="myBtnId" onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Year</button>
    
    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content" onclick="changeYear(event);">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);">2000</a> |
        <a href="javascript:void(0);">2001</a> |
        <a href="javascript:void(0);">2002</a> |
        <a href="javascript:void(0);">2003</a>
    </div>
```

### 2nd Solution: using the "select" HTML element:

```js
function changeYear(event)
{
    let tgtEl = document.getElementById("myBtnId");
    let srcEl = event.target;
    tgtEl.innerHTML = srcEl.value;

    // The one liner version (remove or comment the 3 rows above and de-comment the following one):
    // document.getElementById("myBtnId").innerHTML = event.target.value;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">

    <button id="myBtnId" onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Year</button>
    
    <select id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content" onchange="changeYear(event);">
        <option>2000</option>
        <option>2001</option>
        <option>2002</option>
        <option>2003</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**How it works:**
Basically the function **changeYear(event)** gets the source element that contains the year and extracts its content (innerHTML or value depending on the contingent need) and **inject** such a content into the target element that is the button innerHTML.

Also notice that if you wish to use in place of the `<button></button>` tag the `<input type="button" value="">` tag, you must modify the code as follows:
in the first case using the combination of the **div** and the **a** HTML elements, the part

```
tgtEl.innerHTML = srcEl.value;
```

becomes

```
tgtEl.value = srcEl.value;
```

or

in the second case using the **select** HTML element, the part

```
    tgtEl.innerHTML = srcEl.value;
```

becomes

```
    tgtEl.value = srcEl.value;
```

While the one liner versions will be:

in the first case (with **div+a**):

```
    document.getElementById("myBtnId").value = event.target.innerHTML;
```

in the second case (with the **select**):

```
    document.getElementById("myBtnId").value = event.target.value;
```

### The problem of the javascript:void(0); part:

Also notice that from the HTML part

```
    <a href="javascript:void(0);">200N</a> |
```

you can remove the code **javascript:void(0);** to make the HTML code cleaner and easier to maintain. By doing just that when you click on one of the **a** elements, the page will go to the href="" value that will be the empty string: "": this means that the browser will navigate to a blank page.
To prevent that unwanted behavior you can add to the function a single row:

```
function changeYear(event)
{
    event.preventDefault(); // the row to add to be able remove the code javascript:void(0); from the HTML code

    // here you will keep the rest of the statements as in the original code
}
```

Also you don't even need at all an **a** element: in fact you can use any element you want, like **li** or **div** or **p** and so on. You can even invent your own html element if you wish... Yea it is possible... I am going to demonstrate these possibilities as follows with a 3rd bonus solution that makes use of a mix of a standard **span** HTML element and an element that uses your nickname which is a completely invented or a **custom tag or HTML element**. It should work on modern HTML5 compatible browser.
I will use a little bit of css to style them and distinguish one from the other.

Please have a look at the

### 3rd Bonus Solution: using the "span" HTML element and a custom/invented HTML element/tag:

```js
function changeYear(event)
{
    let tgtEl = document.getElementById("myBtnId");
    let srcEl = event.target;
    tgtEl.innerHTML = srcEl.innerHTML;

    // The one liner version (remove or comment the 3 rows above and de-comment the following one):
    // document.getElementById("myBtnId").innerHTML = event.target.innerHTML;
}
```

```css
#myDropdown
{
  background: yellow;
}

span, useer2332
{
  cursor: pointer;
}

span:hover
{
  background: red;
}

useer2332:hover
{
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">

    <button id="myBtnId" onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Year</button>
    
    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content" onclick="changeYear(event);">
        <span>2000</span> |
        <span>2001</span> |
        <span>2002</span> |
        <span>2003</span> | 
        <useer2332>2004</useer2332> |
        <useer2332>2005</useer2332> |
        <useer2332>2006</useer2332> |
        <useer2332>2007</useer2332>
    </div>
```

One final observation: using the 1nd and the 3rd solution, if the user clicks on the container **div** instead of on the **a** or the **span** or the **useer2332** custom element, the button will be populated with **all** the values of all elements contained into the **div** it self. So you will get an unwanted side effect like 2000 | 2001 |2002 | [...] | 200N ... you don't want that to happen... to prevent this, is necessary to add some code that checks if it was clicked the right element, before executing the statements that populate the button text label.

Check the following solution out and compare its behavior with the behavior of the 1st and 3rd solutions by clicking on the yellow empty space, near the last year, (that is the div it self) and click in the same zone above, you'll notice a very different behavior:

### 3rd Bonus Solution with correction:

```js
function changeYear(event)
{
    if (event.target.tagName == "DIV"){return;}
    let tgtEl = document.getElementById("myBtnId");
    let srcEl = event.target;
    tgtEl.innerHTML = srcEl.innerHTML;

    // The one liner version (remove or comment the 3 rows above and de-comment the following one):
    // document.getElementById("myBtnId").innerHTML = event.target.innerHTML;
}
```

```css
#myDropdown
{
  background: yellow;
}

span, useer2332
{
  cursor: pointer;
}

span:hover
{
  background: red;
}

useer2332:hover
{
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">

    <button id="myBtnId" onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Year</button>
    
    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content" onclick="changeYear(event);">
        <span>2000</span> |
        <span>2001</span> |
        <span>2002</span> |
        <span>2003</span> | 
        <useer2332>2004</useer2332> |
        <useer2332>2005</useer2332> |
        <useer2332>2006</useer2332> |
        <useer2332>2007</useer2332>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining it so well. I now understand what I was doing wrong!!!

Comment: @useer2332 you are welcome... also I added some more things, if you like you can have a look on them too...

Answer (score 1):

1. change "a" tags to "button"
2. instead "this" pass year to your function
   and paste this function inside your script

```
function tiptip(year){
let btn = document.querySelector(".dropbtn")
btn.innerText = year
}
```

that's all